# Show/hide markercluster by category?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm build project using markerCluster,everything work fine to show/hide marker..
but my problem is when marker not display all,cluster still count all marker.
for example: i have 100 marker for all marker status(show & hide),actually 60 are shown and 40 hidden,,the cluster must be totally 60,but i get still cluster count 100..

here my code.

```
 function show(category) 
 {

    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) 
    {
        if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) 
        {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);           
        }        
    }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
}
```

how to make cluster just display 60?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i solved this with jquery

html code where i select my categories:

```
<div id="optionbar-r"><u>(Un)mark to hide/show markers</u><br>
<form id="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked>cat1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="2" checked>cat2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="3" checked>cat3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="4" checked>cat4<br>
</form>
</div>
```

marker

```
var marker = new gm.Marker({
    position: placemark.latlng,
    icon: placemark.style.icon,
    category: stat
});
```

.js code where markers get selected

```
//checkbox elements are in div optionbar-r
var checkbox = document.getElementById("optionbar-r");
$ ("#optionbar-r").click(function() {
        markerclusterer.clearMarkers();//clear clusters
        var selected = new Array();
        //put every checked box into array
        $('#optionbar-r input:checked').each(function() {
                selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });
        //iterate over markersArray and set visibility if category is in array
        for(var i=0; i < markersArray.length-1; i++) {
                if($.inArray(markersArray[i].category, selected) >= 0) {
                        markersArray[i].setVisible(true);
                        markerclusterer.addMarker(markersArray[i]);//recluster all visible markers
                } else {
                        markersArray[i].setVisible(false);
                }
        }
});
```

so basically you need to remove all markers from clusters and recluster only the markers from the category you want to show